# Append lines from .gz file to dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to return a dictionary from a `.gz` file

Here's how my file contents look:

```
[go]{"id": "1", "hello": 12345}
[gsdhgo]{"id": "2", "hello": 123456}
[hff]{"id": "3", "hello": 1234567}
[fska]{"id": "4", "hello": 12345678}
```

My code:

```
import gzip
import re

def removeSquareBrackets():
    contents = {}
    content = []
    with gzip.open('test_gzip_file.txt.gz') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            line = re.sub(r'.*{','{',line)
            line = line[:-1]
            content.append(line)
            contents[content] = []
    return contents


def printFun():
    print removeSquareBrackets()

printFun();
```

Expected output is dictionary of:

```
{"id": "1", "hello": 12345}
{"id": "2", "hello": 123456}
{"id": "3", "hello": 1234567}
{"id": "4", "hello": 12345678}
```

Can anyone correct me or guide me in right direction?

I am getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: You cannot do `contents[content] = []` because content is a mutable type (list) and those can't be hashed and can't be used as dictionary keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 12 of your script you are attempting to use the list content as a key in the dictionary contents. But lists are not a hash-able type.

If you simply want the output you have specified why not just:

`import gzip
import json
content = list()
with gzip.open('tmp.file.gz') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        content.append(json.loads(line[line.find(']')+1:].strip()))`

Perhaps you have some other reason to complicate this with the dictionary and the use of regex?

Comment: The contents in the square brackets [....] can be random. So, I am using regex. I am trying to write it into BigQuery. input collection to WriteToBigQuery should be a collection of dictionaries (each key maps to a BigQuery column), rather than a collection of strings.

Comment: Are the dictionaries in this file the dictionaries in question? Put another way, are each of the strings after the second bracket the JSON output of the dictionaries required to perform the query?

Comment: Changed answer to reflect my understanding of your @PreeteshGaitonde's last comment.